# How to select multiple values in IF or CASE WHEN statments

Tags: mysql

I have a table called basicInfo that contains basic information about a user(for example its gender).

Then I created two tables called userMan and userWoman.

Using the 'gender' value in basicInfo, I want to retrieve information from userMan or userWoman.

For example

```
SELECT
   IF(user.gender='male', (man.height, man.location), (woman.height, woman.location) 
FROM 
   basicInfo AS user 
    LEFT JOIN userMan AS man ON user.id=man.id
    LEFT JOIN userWoman AS woman ON user.id=woman.id;
```

Or

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN user.gender='male'
     THEN man.height, man.location
     ELSE woman.height, woman.location
    END
FROM 
   basicInfo AS user 
    LEFT JOIN userMan AS man ON user.id=man.id
    LEFT JOIN userWoman AS woman ON user.id=woman.id;
```

I have about 17 values to put in the IF or CASE statement. I have to use "user.gender='male'" for every 17 values.

I've thought about using UNION ALL. However, columns that I want to retrieve from userman and userwoman are different.

Is there a better way than using "user.gender='male'" for each column?

Comment: Yes, there is. Create two different SQL-queries in your application

Comment: In your example, the columns you are retrieving are the same and should probably be pulled into a common "parent" table. Can you provide an example where the columns actually are different?

Comment: @lc. I only have three columns that are different. For man, we have isSmoker. For woman, we have coedOrWomans(coed or woman university), isPregnant. I will think about having a parent table.

Comment: Yes, honestly I would put `height`, `location`, etc in the main `user` table, and just keep the *different* columns in `userMan` and `userWoman`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the `UNION ALL` which seems to be the best option, you can also use:

```sql
SELECT
   user.gender, 
   COALESCE(man.height, woman.height) AS height,
   COALESCE(man.location, woman.location) AS location
FROM 
   basicInfo AS user 
      LEFT JOIN userMan AS man 
         ON  user.id = man.id
         AND user.gender = 'male'
      LEFT JOIN userWoman AS woman 
         ON  user.id = woman.id
         AND user.gender = 'female'
WHERE                                     -- this can probably be removed
   user.gender IN ('male', 'female') ;     -- as well
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case it would be more convenient to use `union`:

```
SELECT
    user.gender,
    man.height, 
    man.location
FROM 
   basicInfo AS user 
    LEFT JOIN userMan AS man ON user.id=man.id
WHERE user.gender='male'
UNION
SELECT
    user.gender,
    woman.height, 
    woman.location
FROM 
   basicInfo AS user 
    LEFT JOIN userWoman AS woman ON user.id=woman.id;
WHERE user.gender='female'
```